# CALL SYSTEM USING WS-COMMAND not working on microfocus COBOL on Enterprise server

Tags: powershell, unix, cobol, microfocus

I have a requirement to call a powershell script from microfocus COBOL running on Enterprise server.

The sample script is below:

```
echo "Hello World " | Out-File -FilePath           
 "C:\test.txt"
```

I have added the powershell to be executed from batch script as below:

```
powershell.exe "C:\cbtest.ps1"
```

The structure of WS-COMMAND is as below:

```
01 WS-COMMAND.
   05 COMMAND        PIC X(50) VALUE 
       "/c C:\test.bat".
   05 NULL-VALUE     PIC X VALUE X'00.
```

But, when I am triggering the COBOL prog from a job on microfocus server, a small command prompt window is appearing for some milliseconds, but nothing is happening.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I don't have experience with mainframes, COBOL, or JCL, but your last code snippet looks like it should run `cmd.exe /c C:\test.bat`, which basically means: launch `cmd.exe`, run the script `C:\test.bat` in it, and close (`/c`) after the script terminated. Is PowerShell even available in the environment where you intend to run it?

Comment: yes, but CALL SYSTEM in itself calls cmd.exe using the last command i think. That's why i have just used /c C:\test.bat. Yes, powershell is available in the environment, as if i run the the command "cmd /c C:\test.bat " in  Run, it triggers the powershell properly.

Comment: Did you try running `powershell.exe` with its full path in the batch file?

Comment: As far as I know `CALL SYSTEM` does an internal call to `system()` and starting `/c` won't help there...
As you want to call `powershell.exe` just do so. Please retest and post your actual sample code.
Hint: after `CALL SYSTEM` do something with `RETURN-CODE` (for example `MOVE RETURN-CODE TO PIC-9-08-USAGE-DISPLAY-var   DISPLAY PIC-9-08-USAGE-DISPLAY-var UPON SYSERR` (or a file or wherever) and investigate the code which should give you some hint about what's wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing

```
PIC X VALUE X'00.
```

To

```
PIC X VALUE X'00'.
```

Comment: The missing apostrophe was a "typo" when entering the question on SO and has nothing to do with the problem for which help is being requested. If it had been a problem in the source code, it would have been caught as a _syntax error_ and corrected before posting the code snippet.